# Role based access control with OpenID Connect/OAuth2 via OneLogin and .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, onelogin

I am looking for information and sample code on implementing role based access control with OpenID Connect/OAuth2 and .NET Core with OneLogin.

Any advice would be very much apprecited.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth2 or OIDC can't implement RBAC on their own. They are an authorization or authentication protocol respectively. There is potential for OIDC to carry group/role information as claims in the token, which would require you application to be able to parse the claims and then apply permissions based on the information carried in the claim.

RBAC usually needs an IAM or IGA tool to implement a role catalog/model. Assignment of a role to a user provides an entitlement. That entitlement can be implemented directly on the target application ( via APIs, or via Microsoft AD groups for example ) or an IdP could carry the entitlement in the OIDC token to the target application.

For Onelogin specifically where you have an AD integration, you could drive your entitlements via the memberOf attribute carried in the OIDC token. That's not RBAC though unless the AD group memberships have been assigned via an IAM/IGA tool that assigns those group memberships via roles.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going the IdentityServer4 route.

It's implementation is an abstraction of OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect spec's.

You can start by reading the [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

They have quite good documentation and an abundance of samples available to get you started.

Just as a note as well role based access will not be your go-to here, because tokens that are issued store claims. You can however convert UserRoles to Claims.

Comment: How do I achieve role based access in IdentityServer4? Any pointers? I have looked through all doc and samples from IdentityServer4. But I still don't fully understand how to implement RBAC (they have scope, is it via scope?). On your last paragraph, could you please elaborate on it? To use IdS4, we need to implement database schema, or can I use existing db schema, but use logic to get data from it?